# Get state of show desktop toggle

Tags: c#, taskbar

How do I get the state of the Show-Desktop toggle?

Goal:

> Show the taskbar when show desktop is toggled and desktop is shown
>   Hide the taskbar when show desktop is toggled and windows are restore

Problem:

> I can toggle show desktop and I can show or hide the taskbar but I cannot find a way to determine the state of the "show desktop" toggle.

I'm working in C# in VS 2010 with .net 2.0  (if it has to have later version .net ok, but I suspect the answer is somewhere in win32 with a pinvoke. Just can't find it)

This app is for a touch screen where getting to a auto-hidden taskbar is nearly impossible. Normally the taskbar is hidden but users would like to get to it when they click show desktop. (i.e. please no non-constructive comments on windows doesn't want you to change the autohide state without user permission)

Comment: The only hack I can come up with is to show a small form, toggle show desktop, check the form's window state, show or hide the taskbar based on form's windows state, close the form. It doesn't always work though... It's less than ideal for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Semi-Solution that technically meets my project requirements but not the intent of them:

Show the start menu any time show desktop toggles. Of course the start menu disappears when you click anywhere else but... It was shown.

There are several tutorials on how to do this. [Just Google](http://hanssens.com/2012/show-and-hide-taskbar-and-start-menu-in-c/)